# Azure Function as linked backend to Azure Static Web App missing Azure AD AppRoleAssignments Claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, claims, azure-static-web-app

We have a Static Web App, with an associated C# Function App (using the Bring Your Own Functions AKA "linked backend" approach). Both the Static Web App and Function App are associated with the same Azure AD App Registration.

When we're authenticated with Azure AD and go to the auth endpoint in our Static Web App: `/.auth/me` we see:

```json
{
  "clientPrincipal": {
    "identityProvider": "aad",
    "userId": "d9178465-3847-4d98-9d23-b8b9e403b323",
    "userDetails": "johnny_reilly@hotmail.com",
    "userRoles": ["authenticated", "anonymous"],
    "claims": [
      // ...
      {
        "typ": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier",
        "val": "d9178465-3847-4d98-9d23-b8b9e403b323"
      },
      {
        "typ": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
        "val": "johnny_reilly@hotmail.com"
      },
      {
        "typ": "name",
        "val": "John Reilly"
      },
      {
        "typ": "roles",
        "val": "OurApp.Read"
      },
      // ...
      {
        "typ": "ver",
        "val": "2.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note the claims in there. These include custom claims that we've configured against our Azure AD App Registration such as roles with `OurApp.Read`.

So we can access claims successfully in the Static Web App (the front end). However, the associated Function App does **not** have access to the claims.

It's possible to see this by implementing a function in our Azure Function App which surfaces roles:

```cs
[FunctionName("GetRoles")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "GetRoles")] HttpRequest req
)
{
    var roles = req.HttpContext.User?.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value });

    return new OkObjectResult(roles);
}
```

When this `/api/GetRoles` endpoint is accessed we see this:

```json
[
  {
    "Type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    "Value": "d9178465-3847-4d98-9d23-b8b9e403b323"
  },
  {
    "Type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
    "Value": "johnny_reilly@hotmail.com"
  },
  {
    "Type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
    "Value": "authenticated"
  },
  {
    "Type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
    "Value": "anonymous"
  }
]
```

At first look, this seems great; we have claims! But when we look again we realise that we have far less claims than we might have hoped for. Crucially, our custom claims / app roles like `OurApp.Read` are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer adapted from: https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2022/11/17/azure-ad-claims-static-web-apps-azure-functions - more context available there.

We want our Azure Function App to be able to make use of the same custom claims / app roles that we use for authorization in the Static Web App. How can we achieve this?

### Microsoft Graph API

The answer lies with the Microsoft Graph API. We can interrogate it to get the app role assignments for the user. This will give us the same information that we have in the Static Web App. (Well to be strictly accurate, it will be a slightly different set of claims. But what matters is it will be the app role assignment claims that we want to use for authorization.)

We already have an Azure AD app registration. In order that we can interrogate the Microsoft Graph API, we'll need the following permissions:

- [User.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-85) - to sign in
- [User.Read.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-81) - for acquiring the app role assignments against a user
- [Application.Read.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-4) - to get more information about the app role assignments - allowing us to translate the app role assignments into the claims that we want to use for authorization

We can then write the following:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace MyApp.Auth
{
    public interface IAuthenticatedGraphClientFactory
    {
        (GraphServiceClient, string) GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAndClientId();
    }

    public class AuthenticatedGraphClientFactory : IAuthenticatedGraphClientFactory
    {
        private GraphServiceClient? _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly string _clientId;
        private readonly string _clientSecret;
        private readonly string _tenantId;

        public AuthenticatedGraphClientFactory(
            string clientId,
            string clientSecret,
            string tenantId
        )
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
            _tenantId = tenantId;
        }

        public (GraphServiceClient, string) GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAndClientId()
        {
            var authenticationProvider = CreateAuthenticationProvider();

            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

            return (_graphServiceClient, _clientId);
        }

        private IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            // this specific scope means that application will default to what is defined in the application registration rather than using dynamic scopes
            string[] scopes = new string[]
            {
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            };

            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantId}/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
                .Build();

            return new MsalAuthenticationProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes); ;
        }
    }

    public class MsalAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _clientApplication;
        private readonly string[] _scopes;

        public MsalAuthenticationProvider(IConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes)
        {
            _clientApplication = clientApplication;
            _scopes = scopes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update HttpRequestMessage with credentials
        /// </summary>
        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var token = await GetTokenAsync();

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Acquire Token
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<string?> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            var authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Which we'll use from our `PrincipalService`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace MyApp.Auth
{
    public interface IPrincipalService
    {
        Task<ClaimsPrincipal> GetPrincipal(HttpRequest req);
    }

    public class PrincipalService : IPrincipalService
    {
        readonly ILogger<PrincipalService> _log;
        readonly IAuthenticatedGraphClientFactory _graphClientFactory;

        public PrincipalService(
            IAuthenticatedGraphClientFactory graphClientFactory,
            ILogger<PrincipalService> log
        )
        {
            _graphClientFactory = graphClientFactory;
            _log = log;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> GetPrincipal(HttpRequest req)
        {
            try
            {
                MsClientPrincipal? principal = MakeMsClientPrincipal(req);

                if (principal == null)
                    return new ClaimsPrincipal();

                if (!principal.UserRoles?.Where(NotAnonymous).Any() ?? true)
                    return new ClaimsPrincipal();

                ClaimsIdentity identity = await MakeClaimsIdentity(principal);

                return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.LogError(e, "Error parsing claims principal");
                return new ClaimsPrincipal();
            }
        }

        MsClientPrincipal? MakeMsClientPrincipal(HttpRequest req)
        {
            MsClientPrincipal? principal = null;

            if (req.Headers.TryGetValue("x-ms-client-principal", out var header))
            {
                var data = header.FirstOrDefault();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                    var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                    _log.LogInformation($"x-ms-client-principal: {json}");
                    principal = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MsClientPrincipal>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
                }
            }

            return principal;
        }

        async Task<ClaimsIdentity> MakeClaimsIdentity(MsClientPrincipal principal)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(principal.IdentityProvider);

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, principal.UserId!));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, principal.UserDetails!));

            if (principal.UserRoles != null)
                identity.AddClaims(principal.UserRoles
                    .Where(NotAnonymous)
                    .Select(userRole => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole)));

            var username = principal.UserDetails;
            if (username != null)
            {
                var userAppRoleAssignments = await GetUserAppRoleAssignments(username);
                identity.AddClaims(userAppRoleAssignments
                    .Select(userAppRoleAssignments => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userAppRoleAssignments)));
            }

            return identity;
        }

        static bool NotAnonymous(string r) =>
            !string.Equals(r, "anonymous", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        async Task<string[]> GetUserAppRoleAssignments(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                var (graphClient, clientId) = _graphClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAndClientId();
                _log.LogInformation("Getting AppRoleAssignments for {username}", username);

                var userRoleAssignments = await graphClient.Users[username]
                    .AppRoleAssignments
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

                var roleIds = new List<string>();
                var pageIterator = PageIterator<AppRoleAssignment>
                    .CreatePageIterator(
                        graphClient,
                        userRoleAssignments,
                        // Callback executed for each item in the collection
                        (appRoleAssignment) =>
                        {
                            if (appRoleAssignment.AppRoleId.HasValue && appRoleAssignment.AppRoleId.Value != Guid.Empty)
                                roleIds.Add(appRoleAssignment.AppRoleId.Value.ToString());

                            return true;
                        },
                        // Used to configure subsequent page requests
                        (baseRequest) =>
                        {
                            // Re-add the header to subsequent requests
                            baseRequest.Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
                            return baseRequest;
                        });

                await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

                var applications = await graphClient.Applications
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"appId eq '{clientId}'") // we're only interested in the app that we're running as
                    .GetAsync();

                var appRoleAssignments = applications
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    ?.AppRoles
                    ?.Where(appRole => appRole.Id.HasValue && roleIds.Contains(appRole.Id!.Value.ToString()))
                    .Select(appRole => appRole.Value)
                    .ToArray();

                return appRoleAssignments ?? Array.Empty<string>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.LogError(e, "Error getting AppRoleAssignments");
                return Array.Empty<string>();
            }
        }

        class MsClientPrincipal
        {
            public string? IdentityProvider { get; set; }
            public string? UserId { get; set; }
            public string? UserDetails { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<string>? UserRoles { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

We can then use the `PrincipalService` inside an Azure Function acquire a ClaimsPrincipal that includes our custom claims / app roles like `OurApp.Read`.  Then we can apply authorization as we might hope using that.